# Fixing a lingering immutable reference to self from a method call

Tags: rust

I have a `Needle` that owns a position `current` in a borrowed `tape`. Its `say()` method upsets the compiler.

I'm struggling to understand why `&self` is dragged through the lifetime `'b` before clashing with the call to `advance()`. I've attempted to write in the elided lifetimes.

In `read()`, by the second rule of lifetime elision, `&self` must live at least as long as the returned `&char`. But the call to `read()` in `say()` doesn't need to make a new `&self`. It just passes in `&mut self` with lifetime `'b` and the argument is treated as `&self`. Isn't `&self` dropped at the end of `read()`?

The `&self` feels phantom. I don't know where it exists in the program, or why it's being created.

To further complicate the example, because `tape` isn't owned, `&mut self` isn't able to invalidate `value`.

```
struct Needle<'a> {
    current: usize,
    tape: &'a Vec<char>,
}

impl<'a> Needle<'a> {
    fn say<'b>(&'b mut self) {             // -+--'b
        let value: &'b char = self.read(); //  |
        self.advance();                    //  |
        println!("{}", value);             // -+
    }

    fn read<'c>(&'c self) -> &'c char {
        &self.tape[self.current]
    }

    fn advance<'d>(&'d mut self) {
        self.current += 1;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:9:9
  |
7 |     fn say<'b>(&'b mut self) {
  |            -- lifetime `'b` defined here
8 |         let value: &'b char = self.read();
  |                    --------   ---- immutable borrow occurs here
  |                    |
  |                    type annotation requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'b`
9 |         self.advance();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your signature here says:

```rust
fn read<'c>(&'c self) -> &'c char {
    &self.tape[self.current]
}
```

is "The return value has a lifetime that is equal to `self`." Therefore the borrow remains active for the entire lifetime of `value`. While the immutable borrow is active, a mutable borrow can *not* be made.

And it would make sense, right? You are saying:

1. "Get me a reference from this struct"
2. "I am going to change the struct"
3. "Use the value from that reference"

The compiler does not know you actually did not mutate the vector. So this is actually preventing a bug in your code.